# dyld: Symbol not found: _AVCaptureDeviceTypeBuiltInTelephotoCamera

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

When I try to access the camera devices in AVFoundation and I run the app on my iPad mini running iOS 10.1 the app crashes on runtime and I get this **error**:

> dyld: Symbol not found: _AVCaptureDeviceTypeBuiltInTelephotoCamera
>   Referenced from:
>   /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/B968A732-8216-421B-90E6-FC86E64A6862/pop.app/PlugIns/MessagesExtension.appex/MessagesExtension
>   Expected in: dyld shared cache  in
>   /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/B968A732-8216-421B-90E6-FC86E64A6862/pop.app/PlugIns/MessagesExtension.appex/MessagesExtension
>   (lldb)

It isn't even when this class is running it crashes from app launch. Anyone know why this is? Here is the function where I use these enums.

```
extension AVCaptureDevice{
static func defaultDeviceForPosition(position:AVCaptureDevicePosition) -> AVCaptureDevice?{
    if position == .back{
        if let device = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withDeviceType: AVCaptureDeviceType.builtInWideAngleCamera, mediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, position: .back){
            return device
        }else if let device = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withDeviceType: AVCaptureDeviceType.builtInDuoCamera, mediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, position: .back){
            return device
        }else if let device = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withDeviceType: AVCaptureDeviceType.builtInTelephotoCamera, mediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, position: .back){
            return device
        }else{
            return nil
        }

    }else{
        if let device = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withDeviceType: AVCaptureDeviceType.builtInWideAngleCamera, mediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, position: .front){
            return device
        }else if let device = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withDeviceType: AVCaptureDeviceType.builtInDuoCamera, mediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, position: .front){
            return device
        }else if let device = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withDeviceType: AVCaptureDeviceType.builtInTelephotoCamera, mediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, position: .front){
            return device
        }else{
            return nil
        }
     }
  }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you added the AVFoundation.framework to `Link with Libraries` for your target's `Build Phases`?

Comment: Yes and it works fine with iPhone 6 its just when i switch to the iPad mini where it throws up the errors

Comment: I updated the iPad and switched computers and the problem went away. Guess it was just some sort of strange bug